# How to remap an assembly in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assemblies, remap

I am using a third party software in my C# VS2010 project. I am gettong a warning to remap three of their assemblies.

How do I do that? I have no clue and searching through google i come across how to remap specific MS assemblies and it is much more complicated that I need. I just need to remap their version number.

I just want to know an example that shows what is the simplest way of remapping any assembly?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a "DLL Hell" kind of issue and I did not have to remap the assmeblies just looked through my machine all over and got rid of the specific dlls wherever they were (whether the buidl code had put it there or myself).So I cleaned all DLLs up, then copied the latest versions to where the build needed them.